# Table-valued Data in Common Table Expression

Tags: sql-server, cte, set-returning-functions

Most other databases allow you to generate table values using `VALUES`. As far as I can tell, SQL Server lets you do this with subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('Cornelius','Eversoe', 'cornelius@example.net'),
        ('Ebenezer','Splodge', 'ebenezer@example.net'),
        ('Sylvester','Underbar', 'sylvester@example.net'),
        ('Cynthia','Hyphen-Smythe', 'cynthia@example.net')
) as sq(givenname,familyname,email);
```

but I can’t appear to get it working with CTEs. The best I can do is embed a subquery inside a CTE:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        ('Cornelius','Eversoe', 'cornelius@example.net'),
        ('Ebenezer','Splodge', 'ebenezer@example.net'),
        ('Sylvester','Underbar', 'sylvester@example.net'),
        ('Cynthia','Hyphen-Smythe', 'cynthia@example.net')
    ) as sq(givenname,familyname,email)
)
SELECT * FROM data;
```

I prefer CTEs because of their readability, but is there a more direct way of doing this? For example PostgreSQL, MariaDB (supporting versions) and SQLite all accept this:

```
WITH data(givenname,familyname,email) AS (
    VALUES
        ('Cornelius','Eversoe', 'cornelius@example.net'),
        ('Ebenezer','Splodge', 'ebenezer@example.net'),
        ('Sylvester','Underbar', 'sylvester@example.net'),
        ('Cynthia','Hyphen-Smythe', 'cynthia@example.net')
)
SELECT * FROM data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SQL Server only currently supports [table-valued constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) in a derived table (or the `VALUES` clause of an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement). So, you can use `VALUES` in a join (including apply) or derived table ("subquery") but not a Common Table Expression.

Sadly, T-SQL is lagging in several areas compared with other popular SQL databases, for example [Add support for ANSI standard row value constructors](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894992-add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructo).

Comment: I love the response: Nov 13 2007 — “We’re certainly considering row value constructors for a future release of SQL Server”. Is that the same future version requiring semicolons? Nobody would accuse Microsoft of being over hasty to implement standards.